# Adding d3.js interactive zoomable treemap in RAW

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

Is there a way to add zoomable treemap in [RAW](https://github.com/densitydesign/raw). Using the enter-update-exit pattern of d3.js does not make sense in RAW, so without this functionality, is it possible to add d3.js zoomable treemap in RAW.js

The [RAW](https://github.com/densitydesign/raw) docs in [adding new chart](https://github.com/densitydesign/raw/wiki/Adding-New-Charts) says

> In this way, D3's enter-update-exit pattern does not make too much
>   sense within RAW's charts, since the selection is always empty when
>   passed to the draw function. Since RAW is meant to be a tool for the
>   production of non-interactive visualizations, to be elaborated using
>   vector-graphics tools, this should not be perceived as a limitation,
>   but, at the contrary, as a way to simplify charts' drawing code.

Comment: Given that what you've quoted says "tool for the production of non-interactive visualizations", I wouldn't think that you can use it to create an interactive treemap.

Comment: I have been able to add it. You can check my answer. Its working....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to add zoomable treemap in RAW. Following is the code.

**zoomableTreemap.js**

```
(function(){

    var tree = raw.models.tree();

    var chart = raw.chart()
        .title('Zoomable Treemap')
        .description(
        "A space filling visualization of data hierarchies and proportion between elements. The different hierarchical levels create visual clusters through the subdivision into rectangles proportionally to each element's value. Treemaps are useful to represent the different proportion of nested hierarchical data structures.<br/>Based on <a href='http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582'>http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582</a>")
        .thumbnail("/raw/imgs/treemap.png")
        .category('Hierarchies')
        .model(tree)

    var rawWidth = chart.number()
        .title('Width')
        .defaultValue(100)
        .fitToWidth(true)

    var rawHeight = chart.number()
        .title("Height")
        .defaultValue(500)

    var padding = chart.number()
        .title("Padding")
        .defaultValue(0)

    var colors = chart.color()
        .title("Color scale")

    chart.draw(function (selection, root){

        root.name = 'ZoomableTree';

        var margin = {top: 20, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0},
            width = +rawWidth(),
            height = +rawHeight() - margin.top - margin.bottom,
            formatNumber = d3.format(",d"),
            transitioning;

        var x = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, width])
            .range([0, width]);

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, height])
            .range([0, height]);

        console.log(padding());
        console.log(+padding());
        var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
            .padding(+padding())
            .children(function(d, depth) { return depth ? null : d._children; })
            .sort(function(a, b) { return a.value - b.value; })
            .ratio(height / width * 0.5 * (1 + Math.sqrt(5)))
            // Values are required in d3 treemap layout
            // and our DB table do not have values field in it, so we are going to use 1 for all nodes.
            // The value decides the size/area of rectangle in d3 treemap layout so effectively we are going to have
            // even sized rectangles
            .value(function(d) { return 1; })
            .round(false);

        var svg = selection
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.bottom + margin.top)
            .style("margin-left", -margin.left + "px")
            .style("margin.right", -margin.right + "px")
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
            .style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges")


        var grandparent = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "grandparent");

        grandparent.append("rect")
            .attr("y", -margin.top)
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", margin.top)
            .style("fill", function (d) { return colors()(d.color); })
            .style("stroke","#fff")

        grandparent.append("text")
            .attr("x", 6)
            .attr("y", 6 - margin.top)
            .attr("dy", ".75em");

            initialize(root);
            //console.log(root);
            //throw '';
            accumulate(root);
            layout(root);
            display(root);

            function initialize(root) {
                root.x = root.y = 0;
                root.dx = width;
                root.dy = height;
                root.depth = 0;
            }

            // Aggregate the values for internal nodes. This is normally done by the
            // treemap layout, but not here because  of our custom implementation.
            // We also take a snapshot of the original children (_children) to avoid
            // the children being overwritten when when layout is computed.
            function accumulate(d) {
                return (d._children = d.children)
                    ? d.value = d.children.reduce(function(p, v) { return p + accumulate(v); }, 0)
                    : d.value;
            }

            // Compute the treemap layout recursively such that each group of siblings
            // uses the same size (1×1) rather than the dimensions of the parent cell.
            // This optimizes the layout for the current zoom state. Note that a wrapper
            // object is created for the parent node for each group of siblings so that
            // the parent’s dimensions are not discarded as we recurse. Since each group
            // of sibling was laid out in 1×1, we must rescale to fit using absolute
            // coordinates. This lets us use a viewport to zoom.
            function layout(d) {
                if (d._children) {
                    //console.log(d);
                    //throw 'stop';
                    treemap.nodes({_children: d._children});
                    d._children.forEach(function(c) {
                        //console.log(d);
                        c.x = d.x + c.x * d.dx;
                        c.y = d.y + c.y * d.dy;
                        c.dx *= d.dx;
                        c.dy *= d.dy;
                        c.parent = d;
                        //console.log(c);
                        layout(c);
                    });
                }
            }

            function display(d) {
                grandparent
                    .datum(d.parent)
                    .on("click", transition)
                    .select("text")
                    .text(name(d));

                var g1 = svg.insert("g", ".grandparent")
                    .datum(d)
                    .attr("class", "depth");

                var g = g1.selectAll("g")
                    .data(d._children)
                    .enter().append("g");

                g.filter(function(d) { return d._children; })
                    .classed("children", true)
                    .on("click", transition);

                g.selectAll(".child")
                    .data(function(d) { return d._children || [d]; })
                    .enter().append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "child")
                    .call(rect);

                g.append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "parent")
                    .call(rect)
                    .append("title")
                    .text(function(d) { return formatNumber(d.value); })
                    .style("fill", function (d) { return colors()(d.color); })
                    .style("stroke","#fff")

                g.append("text")
                    .attr("dy", ".75em")
                    .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
                    .call(text);

                function transition(d) {
                    if (transitioning || !d) return;
                    transitioning = true;

                    var g2 = display(d),
                        t1 = g1.transition().duration(750),
                        t2 = g2.transition().duration(750);

                    // Update the domain only after entering new elements.
                    x.domain([d.x, d.x + d.dx]);
                    y.domain([d.y, d.y + d.dy]);

                    // Enable anti-aliasing during the transition.
                    svg.style("shape-rendering", null);

                    // Draw child nodes on top of parent nodes.
                    svg.selectAll(".depth").sort(function(a, b) { return a.depth - b.depth; });

                    // Fade-in entering text.
                    g2.selectAll("text").style("fill-opacity", 0);

                    // Transition to the new view.
                    t1.selectAll("text").call(text).style("fill-opacity", 0);
                    t2.selectAll("text").call(text).style("fill-opacity", 1);
                    t1.selectAll("rect").call(rect);
                    t2.selectAll("rect").call(rect);

                    // Remove the old node when the transition is finished.
                    t1.remove().each("end", function() {
                        svg.style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");
                        transitioning = false;
                    });
                }

                return g;
            }

            function text(text) {
                text.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x) + 6; })
                    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y) + 6; });
            }

            function rect(rect) {
                rect.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
                    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
                    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.x + d.dx) - x(d.x); })
                    .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y + d.dy) - y(d.y); })
                    .style("fill", function (d) { return colors()(d.color); })
                    .style("stroke","#fff");
            }

            function name(d) {
                return d.parent
                    ? name(d.parent) + "." + d.name
                    : d.name;
            }


    })
})();
```

**chart.css**

```
#chart {
    background: #ddd;
}

text {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.grandparent text {
    font-weight: bold;
}

rect {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #fff;
}

rect.parent,
.grandparent rect {
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

.grandparent rect {
    fill: orange;
}

.grandparent:hover rect {
    fill: #ee9700;
}

.children rect.parent,
.grandparent rect {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.children rect.parent {
    fill: #bbb;
    fill-opacity: .5;
}

.children:hover rect.child {
    fill: #bbb;
}
```

**Index.html**

Just include css and js in index page of raw.